# User status change notification webhook

Tags: docusignapi

I knew Docusign could use RestAPI to create users, but most time users will get an activation email from DocuSign and go through set passwords and security questions. After everything is done, the user status will change from Pending to Active in the Docusign Admin portal. Is there any way when user status from pending to active, it could send a notification to the API/Url endpoint to allow us to capture user status change event?

I am trying to build DocuSign and other system integration, I want to create DocuSign users from other systems directly, and monitor the user status in other systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like DocuSign Monitor can send you alerts for the relevant events. See page 20 of the [docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/Protect-your-DocuSign-eSignature-deployment-with-DocuSign-Monitor)

I don't see a `User completed activation` event but perhaps you can use another event, eg `User Login` instead.